# Video settings for HTML

Tags: html, video, html5-video

I want to set the video on the background of my site. Videos with low quality are working, but when i`m trying set Full HD, or HD videos, i've just got the sound and white screen. What restrictions are there?

```
<div class="is_overlay"><video  controls width="300" height="150" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" poster="/videos/bck.jpg">
<source src="videos/bckg720.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video></div>
```

.css:

```
.box,.page {
position:fixed;
top:0;
left:0;
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
z-index:999;
background:rgba(15, 102, 99, 0.5);
color:white;
}
.is_overlay{
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
.is_overlay video {
position: fixed; right: 0; bottom: 0;
min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%;
width: auto; height: auto; z-index: -100;
background: url(/videos/bck.jpg) no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: please provide which code you use for video?

Comment: @DhavalPatel `<div class="is_overlay"><video  controls width="300" height="150" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" poster="/videos/bck.jpg">
<source src="videos/bckg.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video></div>`

Comment: i think your code is proper and it's working fine in my local folder with HD video.Can you please provide site link so i can see it online?